# Android put fragment under recycleview

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

Hi i have create fragment @+id/activity_fragment__eventi__aggiunti where there is a recycleview @+id/reciclerView_eventi_aggiunti , when i instance fragment i put list of cardview in @+id/reciclerView_eventi_aggiunti, this fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fragment__eventi__aggiunti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fra87.eudroid.fragment.Fragment_Eventi_Aggiunti">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclerView_eventi_aggiunti"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want put this fragment in relativelayout @+id/prova of this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_lista__eventi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fra87.eudroid.activity_class.Lista_Eventi">


    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:queryHint="Evento"
        android:id="@+id/cercaEvento"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclerView_eventi"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cercaEvento"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cercaEvento"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/cercaEvento" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/prova">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Salva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/salva_eventi"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reciclerView_eventi"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/reciclerView_eventi" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want inflate fragment in relativelayout @+id/prova but and i want that relativelayout is under @+id/reciclerView_eventi and above button @+id/salva_eventi
How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use an adapter for your RecyclerView.
There is no need to create a fragment for each element of list.

Comment: My idea is: when i click one element of @+id/reciclerView_eventi then open the activity of element, where i can  set and save configuration of element, after i saved i return to main layout where there are list of cardview and under of this list there is another  lsit of item added